# Android- inserting external image from URL to placeholder in the app

Tags: android, android-layout

Pretty new to Android development, haven't found the answer needed.

I have an ImageView some layout.xml:

```
  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Instead the `placeholder`, I want to load some specific image from url that i have.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: You can only do it in code (Java). OR, first download the image, then put it in a drawable folder and **then** refer it from your layout (xml).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein thanks, i used the Picassa library that was suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) Library for android to download images from url and display onto `ImageView`

Its very easy to use like this

`Picasso.with(context).load("http://your_image_url").into(your_imageView);`

Comment: Thanks, amazing library. Works great!

Answer (score 4):

for download the image for url ,first download that image and saved it in Bitmap

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream in = null;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;

try {
in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(),IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
copy(in, out);
out.flush();

final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//options.inSampleSize = 1;

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
} finally {
closeStream(in);
closeStream(out);
}

return bitmap;
```

Than you can set image by call that method

```
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
  ImageView bmImage;

  public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
      this.bmImage = bmImage;
  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String urldisplay = urls[0];
      Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
      try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return mIcon11;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
  }
}
```

And call from your onCreate() method using:

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1))
        .execute(MY_URL_STRING);
```

Dont forget to add below permission in your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try ImageLoader,you can download it here https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader